# pandas.to_datetime() is not start from 18:00 when plotting

Tags: python, pandas

I want to plot a graph starting from 18:00 and end at the next day at 08:13. However, when I try to plot a graph is started at 00:00 instead of 18:00

example time:

```
21 18:00:01       depth _ 1
21 18:00:02       depth _ 1
21 18:00:03       depth _ 1
21 18:00:05       depth _ 1
21 18:00:06       depth _ 1
21 18:00:07       depth _ 1
...and so on
```

My code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as md
import datetime as dt


file = "xxx_depth-2021-01-21_180001.txt"
df = pd.read_csv(file, delim_whitespace=True, names=['Date', 'Time', 'Description', 'None', 'Value'])
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format= '%H:%M:%S', utc= True, dayfirst=True).dt.time
df.plot(x='Time', y='Value')
plt.xticks( rotation=90)

plt.ylabel('Queue')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

Comment: You can use `set_xlim` to start x range from a certain point

Comment: `ax.set_xlim([datetime.time(18, 0), datetime.time(some end time)])` or `ax.set_xlim(left=datetime.time(18, 0))`.